# Given array of integers, find the maximal possible sum of some of its k consecutive elements

Tags: c++

```
int sum(vector<int> inputArray, int k, int n)
{
    int s=0;
    for(int i=n; i<n+k; i++)
    {
        s = inputArray[i] + s;
    }
            
    return s;
}


int solution(vector<int> inputArray, int k) {
    
    vector<int> answer;
    int ans;
   
    
    for(int i=0; i< inputArray.size()-k+1; i++)
    {   
        ans = sum(inputArray, k, i);
        answer.push_back(ans);
    }
    
    int a = *max_element(answer.begin(), answer.end());
    
    return a;
}
```

My code gets one hidden test case wrong in codesignal. I am not able to figure it out.
Tests passed: 19/20. Execution time limit exceeded: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

Comment: You copy the `vector` every time you call `sum`. That seems terribly unnecessary: `int sum(const vector<int>& inputArray, int k, int n) { int s = 0; for(int i=n; i<n+k; i++) s += inputArray[i]; return s; }` would be a lot cheaper.

Comment: Great! You're welcome!